# Limited user premissions in team foundation server

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs, permissions

Can I setup Team Foundation Server in such a manner that every uer have only access to some source code files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to this question is Yes, but it's not straight forward.

First of all, you will have to add user to the TFS Project (as a Reader or Contributor). Then in the Source Control Explorer, right click on folder or file and select properties. On the Security tab you have options to apply specific permissions to groups and or users.

So your option would be to remove all unnecessary permissions for the required users, and assign them per folder/file. I'm not sure though if you remove Read from parent folder you will have possibility to access folders/files below.

Answer (score 0):

You can make different team projects for the different types of users.